# How to set CSS file to whole application JafaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I want to set one css file to my whole application.
I read several similar topic, but I didn't find solution.
This is my code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/MainView.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root); 
    scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("modena_dark.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

There is no error, just stylesheet doesn't work and app window looks standard.
File "modena_dark.css" is in the same directory as file with this code.

### Heading

Comment: please provide an excerpt of modena_dark.css to see if it's formatted correctly.

Comment: css file should be present at the compiled class level.

Comment: verify that the build includes the correct css file into output folder. you can use below code to see what its printing:-

System.out.println(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

Answer (score 0):

If your .css file is in the same directory as your java class, try using:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("/yourpackage/modena_dark.css");
```

This works for me without any problems.

Comment: This won't work if the CSS file is inside the .jar file.

Comment: @Itai Actually it works for me, even in an `.jar` file. I don't know why, but `getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm()` isn't working for me.